# convert delimited string to hierarchical JSON in python

Tags: python, json

How do I convert delimited strings into a hierarchical JSON in Python? (I saw a [solution for a similar question in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232753/convert-delimited-string-into-hierarchical-json-with-jquery). I have been trying to find a Python solution for the same.)

The goal is to generate a hierarchical JSON of categories from a bunch of URLs which might look like:

```
sport/tennis/grandslams  
sport/chess  
sport/chess/players/men  
sport/tennis  
sport/cricket/stadiums  
sport/tennis/players
```

Comment: The solution depends on your input. What's your input?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could achieve this with dictionnaries :

```
initial = ["Fred-Jim","Fred","Fred-Jim-Bob", "Fred-Jim-Jack", "John", "John-Jim"]

result = {}

for item in initial:
    hierarchy = item.split('-')
    local_result = result
    for node in hierarchy:
        local_result = local_result.setdefault(node, {})

print result
```

Will give you :

```
{
    'John': {
        'Jim': {}
    }, 
    'Fred': {
        'Jim': {
            'Bob': {},
            'Jack': {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ironically, this was exactly what I needed in JS...in 2014

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `json.dumps()` from the `json` module?

edit:
oh, ok, I get you now.  Maybe something like:

```
#paths is a list of strings containing the paths you are scraping from your site.
hierarchy = {}
for path in paths:
    cursor = hierarchy
    for part in path.split('/'):
        if part not in cursor:
            cursor[part] = {}
        cursor = cursor[part]
```

Comment: i am trying to create hierarchically formatted data from the above list of urls, which i can then feed to json.dumps so that i can get a hierarchical json. This example in jQuery perfectly illustrates what I want to achieve http://stackoverflow.com/a/6232943/435089