# Directory listing to JSON using Java

Tags: java, json

I need to have the below list of folders (directory listing) to be converted to JSON using Java:

```
"ListDirectories/"
"ListDirectories/folder1/"
"ListDirectories/folder1/folder3/"
"ListDirectories/folder2/"
```

And I want JSON as:

```
String data = "{text: 'ListDirectories',nodes:[{text:'folder1',nodes:[{text:'folder3'}]},{text:'folder2}]}";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would go about this would be to create a file system 'tree' by parsing the inputs and then converting this tree to a json.

A tree would have nodes as :

```
Node {
String name;
List<Node> children;
}
```

Try to form this tree when parsing the inputs. When a node is not there, create it in the tree.

Implement the toJSON(tree) by converting the tree to a JSON recursively.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try doing that. Sorry for my poor knowledge here, but what is creating file system tree here

Comment: Sure! Usually, when you want to store/parse a file system, one of the approaches you could take is to create a tree which represents it.
ListDirectories has two children folder1 and folder2, folder1 has one child : folder3

Answer (score 1):

You can also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232753/convert-delimited-string-into-hierarchical-json-with-jquery). Here its solving using jquery , but similar approach can be taken to solve using java.